# PropTypes: How to check for an enum of objects?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have an array of possible fields:

```
export const fields = [
  { type: 'select', defaultValue: MAINTAIN, name: TENDENCY },
  { type: 'select', defaultValue: DISTANT_ACQUAINTANCE, name: GROUP },
  { type: 'input', defaultValue: '', name: FIRST_NAME },
  { type: 'input', defaultValue: '', name: LAST_NAME },
  { type: 'input', defaultValue: '', name: CITY },
  { type: 'input', defaultValue: '', name: COMPANY },
  { type: 'input', defaultValue: '', name: POSITION },
];
```

And e.g. `const FIRSTNAME = 'firstName';`.

I render these fields in a `<ContactCell />` component. I tried to do PropTypes checks like this:

```
ContactCell.propTypes = {
  field: PropTypes.oneOf(fields).isRequired,
  handleChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

But when I render a ContactCell like this:

```
const createContactCell = (props = {}) =>
  render(<ContactCell {...props} handleChange={() => {}} />);

const props = {
  value: 'Mike',
  field: { type: 'input', defaultValue: '', name: 'firstName' },
};
createContactCell(props);
```

I get the error:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `field` of value `[object Object]` supplied to `ContactCell`, expected one of [{"type":"select","defaultValue":"maintain","name":"tendency"},{"type":"select","defaultValue":"distantAcquaintance","name":"group"},{"type":"input","defaultValue":"","name":"firstName"},{"type":"input","defaultValue":"","name":"lastName"},{"type":"input","defaultValue":"","name":"city"},{"type":"input","defaultValue":"","name":"company"},{"type":"input","defaultValue":"","name":"position"}].
    in ContactCell
```

How do you properly do PropType checks with with an array of possible objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `oneOf` prop type will check for references, but if you want to check if all the properties match one of the objects in the `fields` array you could create a custom prop type that uses e.g. Lodash [`isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isEqual) to compare the prop against the objects in the `fields` array.

```
const fields = [
  { type: "select", defaultValue: MAINTAIN, name: TENDENCY },
  { type: "select", defaultValue: DISTANT_ACQUAINTANCE, name: GROUP },
  { type: "input", defaultValue: "", name: FIRST_NAME },
  { type: "input", defaultValue: "", name: LAST_NAME },
  { type: "input", defaultValue: "", name: CITY },
  { type: "input", defaultValue: "", name: COMPANY },
  { type: "input", defaultValue: "", name: POSITION }
];

ContactCell.propTypes = {
  handleChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  field: function(props, propName, componentName) {
    if (
      propName === "field" &&
      !fields.some(field => _.isEqual(props.field, field))
    ) {
      return new Error(
        "Invalid prop `field` supplied to `ContactCell`. Validation failed."
      );
    }
  }
};
```